# Split a page in half while still filling the page

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm having trouble aligning two miniboxes on a small page, but I can't get it quite right.

I'd like them to each take up half of the page within the margin (with the red one containing text that is upside down).

Right now, I've been tuning the 0.45 in `\begin{minpage}[t][0.45\textheight]` and the -5mm in `\vspace{-5mm}` between the boxes and this is the best alignment I can get.

[image]

As you can see, the red box doesn't reach the bottom margin (which I want it to do).

If I don't use `\vspace` the best I can get is setting `0.41\textheight`

[image]

It would be nice to be able to specify `0.5\textheight` or `0.5\textheight-\borderwidthwidth` if that makes more sense.

The `\vspace{-5mm}` would also be nice to specify relative to an actual length in case my page size changes.  I tried things like `\usepackage[skip=0mm,parfill=0mm]{parskip}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}, but without` \vspace{...}` I always had space between my minipages.

Document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=88mm,paperwidth=62mm,top=4mm,bottom=4mm,right=4mm,left=4mm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newenvironment{BlueBox}{
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=blue!20]
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight]{\textwidth}
  \raggedright
}{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{RedBox}{
  \begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=red!20]
  \begin{turn}{180}
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight]{\textwidth}
  \raggedright
}{
  \end{minipage}
  \end{turn}
  \end{mdframed}
}


\begin{document}
\raggedright

\begin{BlueBox}
\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{BlueBox}

\vspace{-5mm}

\begin{RedBox}
\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{RedBox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should comment the end-of-lines, e.g., after a `minipage`. And AFAIK with `framemethod=tikz` the boxes have depth. Maybe something like `\vskip-\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+\baselineskip+\parskip+\lineskip\relax` could help. Sorry, but I never use `mdframed`, but `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Tried commenting the end of every line.  I'll give `tcolorbox` a try, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with `tcolorbox` which allows you to only use one single environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperheight=88mm, 
    paperwidth=62mm,
    margin=4mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newenvironment{BlueBox}{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    colback=blue!20, 
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    height=0.5\textheight, 
    beforeafter skip balanced=0pt,
    sharp corners
  ]
  \raggedright
}{
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newenvironment{RedBox}{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, 
    tikz={rotate=180},
    colback=red!20, 
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0.4pt,
    height=0.5\textheight, 
    beforeafter skip balanced=0pt,
    sharp corners
  ]
  \raggedright
}{
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{BlueBox}
\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{BlueBox}
\begin{RedBox}
\raggedright Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.
\end{RedBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like that this uses `0.5\textheight`, that makes sense.  I also liked how you replaced the ever-increasing stack of minpage/rotate/mdframed with something much simpler.  Also, simplifying the geometry was a nice touch.

Comment: @Stewart Actually, you could even have empty lines in your code between the environments this way.